# Determining current in an electric circuit

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

[image]

Determine the current passing through R3.

Given:

$R_1=5 \Omega$

$R_2=5 \Omega$

$R_3=10 \Omega$

$V_1=100 V$

$Is_2=5 A$

Attempt to solve this :

**Using Mesh current analysis**:
[image]
**Mesh 1**:

$-V_1+R_1(I_1-Is_2)+R_2(I_1-I_2)=0$

$-100+5(I_1-5)+5(I_1-I_2)=0$

$10I_1-5I_2=125$

**Mesh 2**:

$5(I_2-I_1)+10(I_2-Is_2)+5i'=0$

$i'=I_1-Is_2$

This would give us $I_2=Is_2=5A$

Hence $I_1=15A$

The current going through R_3 would be equal to $I_2-Is_2=5-5=0A$

However this answer doesn't seme logical , I can't imagine that there's no current going through R3 since the current $i'$ should obviously split into $R_2$ and $R_3$.

I'd be grateful if someone could point out any mistakes in my calculations.

Comment: Won't it be $I_2 + I_ 1$ in Mesh -2 ...?

Comment: Do you mean the current going through $R_2$?

Comment: Yes ... Through $R_2$ ...

Comment: No , why would it be $I_2 + I_1$? I’m pretty sure it’s $I_2-I_1$

Comment: Both the batteries tend to send current across $R_1$ and $R_3$ in opposite ways , which combine in $R_2$ ... That's my reasoning ...

Comment: $I_2$ is the current passing through the lower black wire and $I_1$ through the lower green wire , hence let $x$ be the current passing through $R_2$ , applying KCL on the lower node we get $I_2=I_1+x \implies x=I_2-I_1$.

Comment: They'll be $I_1 + I_2 = x $...

Comment: $I_2$ splits into $I_1$ and $x$

Comment: Taking the bottom line as zero volts then the central red node is at a potential of +50 V with a current of 10 A passing through R1. The node at the top of the  CCVS is at +50 V so the potential difference across R3 is zero. The current from the current source just circulates around the periphery of the circuit.

Comment: I get it now I thought It was necessary for a current to appear across R3 , hence why I doubted my calculations.